# How to use Callback function to get language in Tizen?

Tags: c, linux, tizen, tizen-native-app

I want to write a native application in c to get the value of language in Tizen. The compiled c code must be run on the Tizen phone and I need to get the Value of language. The callback function i got from Tizen source is

```
int app_cb_broker_appcore_lang_changed(void *data)
{
    app_language_changed_cb lang_changed_cb;

    lang_changed_cb = app_context.callbacks->language_changed;

    if (lang_changed_cb != NULL)
    {
            lang_changed_cb(app_context.user_data);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How to use this function to get the value of current language?

Comment: Doesn't Tizen support the LANG environment variable?  I believe it does.

Comment: lang variable is available in tizen apps using html5. i need to write a native code in c. and another important point is while using lang variable i need to poll every time to check whether there is a change in the value of lang. so i need this callback

Comment: No, I mean a unix environment variable.  What do you get from `getenv("LANG")`.  And why on earth would you want to poll for changes?

Comment: i am creating a native app that needs to change its language according to the language in tizen. its not an usual html5 app. the methode u r telling me may be a solution. but i need callback function to get this.

Comment: i need a solution to use the above callback to get the language value

Comment: /opt/var/kdb/db/menu_widget/language is the path in tizen device that shows the LANG varaible, u r telling me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are trying to work with the Native API and Tizen is a quite new enterprise and even though Tizen is documented on the Web API side it is not fully documented on Native API, why don't try to ask some of people that are developing it they might know better.

On their site they give an irc room https://www.tizen.org/community/irc:

> Primary Channel: 
>   `#tizen at irc.freenode.net: 24/7 open discussion.`

Or the mailing list:
https://www.tizen.org/community/mailing-lists

*Later edit:* I went myself on that IRC room and asked for some details on deployment and Native API and I received (after half an hour) this link: http://giscaro.wordpress.com/ so there can be a response there. I would have asked your question but I don't know what you want to do exactly.
If you do not have a IRC client installed you can use this [link to login automatically to the `#tizen`](http://webchat.freenode.net/?randomnick=1&channels=tizen&uio=d4) chat room via a webchat, with a random username(You must complete Recapcha).